# PostgreSQL проверка очередности строк

Tags: postgresql

Мне нужен порядок в строках, к примеру строки должны идти как: true, false, true, false ... а не true, true, false, false, true ... Получается я должен при каждом INSERT делать SELECT последней строки и проверять есть ли она или есть другие пути?

Comment: А причем тут insert ? В таблице БД нет понятия порядка строк. строки не хранятся в том порядке, в котором вы их вставляете. порядок в котором вернутся строки может быть произвольным. о порядке строк имеет смысл говорить уже тогда когда вы их получаете, указанием нужного order by в запросе

Comment: @Mike мне нужно журналировать вход и выход пользователя в систему, если я уже добавил запись что пользователь вышел дальше нет смысла добавлять такую же запись пока не будет записи что он вошел. У записи есть id и я делаю SELECT сортируя по id

Comment: А если пользователь не вышел и решил войти с другого компа/вкладки/браузера у нас уже два входа и на них надо 2 выхода. А по хорошему надо давать сеансу свой id и просто отмечать в той же записи дату выхода например, а не делать 2 записи. Но если хочется две, то да, единственный путь, это проверить при insert наличие противоречивой записи